# Yii2 FullCalendar: how to add link button

Tags: php, html, yii2, fullcalendar, yii2-advanced-app

I am using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) , its work perfectly , but i need to add href to the button className='btn' when i click on redirect to view page .

my code in controller :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   $events = event::find()->all();
   $taskes=[];
   foreach ($events as $eve) 
   {
      $event1 = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
      $patient = patient::findOne($eve->patient_id);
      $event1->className='btn'; // this button that i need to add link to :  ['site/view', 'id' => $id ]  
      $event1->id = $eve->id;
      $event1->title = $patient->patient_name;
      $event1->start = $eve->event_date;
      $taskes[] = $event1;
   }
      return $this->render('index', [
      'events'=>$taskes,
    ]);
}
```

[image: the button i need add link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  you can make like this:

```
...
$event1->url = Url::to(['site/view', 'id' => $id ]);
...
```

Look in the documentation - http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: Thank you very much .. I tried it , and it works as I want, really appreciate your help ... :)